# Who to display image in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm very new to Django so I saved an image into the database inside my models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    content = models.TextField()
    active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/pictures', null=True)
```

now I want to display this image and I used the get_absolute_url method to get the current data from a row inside the db:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/blog/{self.id}'
```

In the views.py I return a renderfun with the params  `'article':get_object_or_404(Article, id=my_id)`.
Now in my template index.html I have this

```
{% block content %}
    {{ article.content }}
    <img src="{{ article.picture }}" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
{% endblock %}
```

But if I open the developer console in chrome the img path is the same I set in models.py. The document/pictures folder is at the root of the django app.
I tried to move it into the current app (Blog) but this also doesnt work. Do I have to set the media path in the settings.py ?
I use django 3 and sqlite3 as db

Comment: Use `{{ article.picture.url }}`.

Comment: I tried but It is not working

Comment: did you add the media paths to your `urls.py`?

Comment: ok sorry i have to clean the all exist articles, the new one works, thanks